# Getting 'Promise { <pending> }' message when using async-await to perform tcp client

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am performing tcp client using `telnet-client` node module.

```
const Telnet = require('telnet-client')

async function wazuhRun(host) {
  let connection = new Telnet()
  let ErrCode = -1;

  let params = {
    host: host,
    port: 2345,
    negotiationMandatory: false,
    timeout: 1500
  }

  try {
  await connection.connect(params)
  ErrCode = 0;
  } catch(error) {
  ErrCode = -1;
  }
  return ErrCode;
}

const code = wazuhRun('linux345');
console.log(code);
```

On running above code, I am getting `Promise { <pending> }`

Please suggest what might be missing in my code

Comment: const code = await wazuhRun('linux345') inside an async function will fix the problem.

Comment: In the shown code, there is nothing missing. `wazuhRun` returns a Promise, so you have to use `await` or `.then` to get it's resolved result.

Comment: It is returning null value. It should return `0` or `-1`

Comment: Please show a [mcve] where the code returns `null`. For the given code `wazuhRun` would be either be rejected or resolve to `0` or `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using it outside of a async function you need to treat it as a Promise:

```
wazuhRun('linux345').then((result) => console.log(result));
```

async functions are a syntatic sugar around Promises, they get translated into Promises which is why you get Promise pending.

If you were calling it from inside another async function you could use:

```
const code = await wazuhRun('linux345');
```

EDIT:
About the null return, it could be that your function throws an error before your try/catch.

```
 wazuhRun('linux345')
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

By adding a catch handler to your Promise you'll be able to see all errors thrown from within your async function.

Comment: you can use await only inside async function.

Comment: @AS_ this is true for now but [v8.dev/features/top-level-await:](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) `[...]Top-level await enables developers to use the await keyword outside of async functions. It acts like a big async function causing other modules who import them to wait before they start evaluating their body.[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Use wazuhRun('linux345').then() the it will work fine.

```
const Telnet = require('telnet-client')

async function wazuhRun(host) {
  let connection = new Telnet()
  let ErrCode = -1;

  let params = {
    host: host,
    port: 2345,
    negotiationMandatory: false,
    timeout: 1500
  }

  try {
  await connection.connect(params)
  ErrCode = 0;
  } catch(error) {
  ErrCode = -1;
  }
  return ErrCode;
}

wazuhRun('linux345').then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
```